# Rendering a read-only form from multiple sets of structured data, use of useState and useEffect

Tags: react.js, jsx

This fairly simplistic working example covers:

- Handling multiple sets of data without code repetition
- Fetching data and using useEffect to process the output when completed
- Changing from loading screen to data display/error message using conditional return statements
- No use of async/await

Looking for some suggestions on best practices.

```
function ReadOnly_Form_Manager({SubForms_upto})
{
  
  const [readonly_subforms, SET_readonly_subforms] = useState([]);

  //This will intrate and fetch the data for each subform
  for(var i=1;i<=SubForms_upto;i++)
  {
    SubForm_iterator(i);
  }

  //This handles fetches for each subform
  function SubForm_iterator(i)
  {
    //Preparing to fetch the data
    const [fetch_result, SET_fetch_result] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      const full_url = "https://....." + i; //The i is set dynamically
      const fetch_params = {method: 'GET', headers: "..."};

      Generic_Fetch_Handler(full_url,fetch_params,SET_fetch_result); //This functions sets the output using the SET_fetch_result
    }, []);

    //Retreiving the fetched data
    useEffect(() => {
      if(fetch_result)
      {
        if(fetch_result.status == "success")
        {
          const holder_array = fetch_result.resp_data;

          //This checks for repeat fetches, and discards duplicates
          var repeat_checker = false;
          for(var i=0;i<readonly_subforms.length;i++)
          {
            if(JSON.stringify(readonly_subforms[i]) === JSON.stringify(holder_array))
            {
              repeat_checker = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if(repeat_checker === false)
          {
            //The data is stored as an array of arrays
            SET_readonly_subforms(
              current_array => [...current_array, holder_array]
            );
          }
        }
        else
        {
          SET_readonly_subforms(
            {
              error_message: "Fetch Error",
              error_details: fetch_result.resp_data
            }
          );
        }
      }
    }, [fetch_result]);
  }
  
  if(readonly_subforms)
  {
    if(readonly_subforms.error_message)
    {
      return(
        <>
          <h2>Error</h2>
          <p>{readonly_subforms.error_message}</p>
        </>
      )
    }
    else if(readonly_subforms.length > 0)
    {
      return (
        <>
          { //Displaying as a basic static HTML
            readonly_subforms.map( readonly_subform => (
              <Generic_Form_Displayer readonly_subform={readonly_subform} />
            ))
          }
        </>
      );
    }
    else
    {
      return (
        <>
          <h2>Loading...</h2>
        </>
      );
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some issues with your code:

- loading state is incorrect. Once your first request gets back with some data, the component renders the response. It re-renders when `readonly_subforms` updates every time afterwards, which isn't a nice user experience. Hence you should have a top-level loading state that covers for all the requests.
- Since there is no control on how you display your responses. The forms will be displayed in the order same as the order of the requests' arrival. Whether this is a problem depends on your business requirements.
- `SET_readonly_subforms` sets an object (not array) on request errored. You should not mutate the type of the `readonly_subforms` state. Keeping the type consistent is always the best practice.
- You can simplify how you check if there is duplicate response data by `Array.find`. Out of curiosity, why can a different request url return a same response? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Overall, I don't see why can't we just use `Promise.all` to achieve the same results. It's easier, cleaner and better, which also resolves all the issues mentioned above.

Comment: _Top level loading state_: Good idea. This state can be triggered after the array length equals the number of subforms(i.e. all data received)

_Forms displayed in order they arrive_: Yes, the schema of the form should be fetched separately to arrange the fields correctly

_Type change during error_: Good point. Would storing the error in position zero of an array keep things consistent or should I use a different variable for the error?

_Array.find_: Or perhaps even the Array.includes function? Good idea.

Comment: _Duplicate elements in array_: Different URLs don't return the same response. This is just some side effect of Dev mode in react where everything gets called twice.

This problem shouldn't exist in production, but I figured no harm in keeping it. Especially if the code is ever run twice during a re-render or something.

_Promises_: Admittedly I'm not very familiar with raw promises. But will look it up, thanks.

Comment: In any case, comparing responses is the worst idea to prevent the requests from being sent twice. Try to prevent the duplicate calls before they are sent to the server

Comment: "Would storing the error in position zero of an array keep things consistent or should I use a different variable for the error?" You can use `{type: 'success' | 'error', responseData: ...}[]`